# How to implement mixed font size text on UILabel with core text in IOS 5?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-text

How to implement UILabel with "**this**-*kind*-of-***text***" (also mixing font size) for iOS 5.0? I gave a try with NSAttributedString but it appears most [attributes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html) of its attribute constants are for iOS 6.0 only. In iOS 5, such task might be implemented using webview. I also tried [an example](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2011/03/attributed-strings-in-ios.html) to use core text but the program crashes with bad access if I try to use partial range. Any working code fragments would be appreciated.

Comment: this [project](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel) saved me a lot of time playing with labels and formatted text

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with UILabel on iOS 5 — as you discovered, UILabel only supports rich text on iOS 6.

Take a look at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8322020/display-nsattributedstring-using-coretext) for how you could easily use Core Text to draw the string. (lnafziger's answer is simpler than mine.)

Answer (score 0):

Try [OHAttributedLabel](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel), this might work for you :)