# How to properly compensate CGContextRef coordinate system, so the origin is at the top left corner

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring, core-text

I'm trying to draw text using CoreText. I have the following code:

```
CGContextRef uiContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

NSMutableDictionary<NSAttributedStringKey,id> *attributes = [NSMutableDictionary<NSAttributedStringKey,id> new];
[attributes setObject:UIColor.redColor forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];
[attributes setObject:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:40] forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
NSAttributedString *attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Str" attributes:attributes];

CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddRect(path, nil, CGRectMake(0, 50, attrString.size.width, attrString.size.height));
CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((CFAttributedStringRef)attrString);
CTFrameRef frame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, CFRangeMake(0, attrString.length), path, nil);

CTFrameDraw(frame, uiContext);
```

With the above code, text is placed properly, but is mirrored across y-direction [image: proper origin, wrong text orientation]

So, I tried to apply translate and scale transformation, which helped with text, but now it's placed at to bottom left corner, which isn't the desired behavior.

```
CGContextSetTextMatrix(uiContext, CGAffineTransformIdentity);
CGContextTranslateCTM(uiContext, 0.0, self.bounds.size.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(uiContext, 1.0, -1.0);
```

[image: wrong origin, proper orientation]

Is there any ideas what am I missing here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Where does this 50 value for the y origin come from on this line?

```
CGPathAddRect(path, nil, CGRectMake(0, 50, attrString.size.width, attrString.size.height));
```

If you're starting from the lower left y coordinate, that 50 value will start the path drawing y origin 50 up from that.

You should be able to adjust the y origin to be offset from the top by using the container view's height (that you'd like to draw the text into) minus the attrString.size.height.

Here's an example of what it might look like if you are doing the drawing a custom view's subclass' `drawRect:rect`:

```
CGPathAddRect(path, nil, CGRectMake(0, rect.size.height - attrString.size.height, attrString.size.width, attrString.size.height));
```

Which would result in this:

[image: CoreTextDrawing upper left hand corner of container view]

Comment: yep, that going to work, and actually, I was considering this as solution, but I though that there is more clear way of doing that, this will introduce such calculations for everything in the code, and I would like to omit that....

Comment: as for 50 value - it's used to offset from the top bottom of the screen, to omit overlapping with time at the very top of safe area

Answer (score 0):

How about this one:

swift:

```
   CGContextSetTextMatrix(uiContext, CGAffineTransform(a: 1.0, b: 0.0, c: 0.0, d: -1.0, tx: 0.0, ty: 0.0))
```

Objective c:

```
    CGContextSetTextMatrix(uiContext, CGAffineTransformMake(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0));
```

To simple setting, do the following:

```
   CGPathAddRect(path,nil, CGRectMake(0, 0, attrString.size.width, 1.5 * attrString.size.height));
```

instead of:

```
     CGPathAddRect(path, nil, CGRectMake(0, 50, attrString.size.width, attrString.size.height));
```

Comment: in swift it behaves differently comparing to obj-c

Comment: I don't mean that I can't translate to obj-c from swift, the problem is that CoreText behaves differently (try it our for yourself)

Comment: @nrudnyk, you may try the simple one.

Comment: The difference between this and yours is only adjusting the character transform not the frame.

Comment: Such vertical shift is due to the origin of NSAttributeString is on its baseline by default, not in its middle vertical line. So the difference can be done by enlarging the drawing rects.